# setting focus following validation of field with onblur not working

Tags: javascript, validation

After spending an hour or more looking for some alternative, I'm coming up empty.  Upon losing focus, a function is called, the portion to set focus back to the calling field upon validation fail is not working...

example here:
http://owenparker.com/test/testval.php

```js
var emptyString = /^$/;
function validatePresent(valfield,
  infofield) {
  var stat = commonCheck(valfield, infofield, true);
  if (stat != proceed) return stat;

  msg(infofield, "warn", "");
  return true;
}

var proceed = 2;

function commonCheck(valfield,
  infofield,
  required) {
  if (!document.getElementById)
    return true; // not available on this browser - leave validation to the server
  var infoelem = document.getElementById(infofield);
  if (!infoelem.firstChild) return true;
  if (infoelem.firstChild.nodeType != Node.TEXT_NODE) return true;

  if (emptyString.test(valfield.value)) {
    if (required) {
      msg(infofield, "error", "ERROR: required");
      setfocus(valfield);
      return false;
    } else {
      msg(infofield, "warn", ""); // OK
      return true;
    }
  }
  return proceed;
}

function msg(fld,
  msgtype,
  message) {
  var dispmessage;
  if (emptyString.test(message))
    dispmessage = String.fromCharCode(160);
  else
    dispmessage = message;

  var elem = document.getElementById(fld);
  elem.firstChild.nodeValue = dispmessage;

  elem.className = msgtype; 
}

function setFocusDelayed()
{
  global_valfield.focus();
}

function setfocus(valfield)
{
  // save valfield in global variable so value retained when routine exits
  global_valfield = valfield;
  setTimeout( 'setFocusDelayed()', 100 );
}
```

```html
<table border=0 width=500px>
  <tr>
    <td>Misc 1:&nbsp;
      <input name="misc1" id="misc1" type="text" size="10" tabindex=1 autofocus onblur="validatePresent(this, 'inf_misc1');">
      <div id="inf_misc1">&nbsp;</div>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Whatever:&nbsp;
      <select name="whatever" id="whatever" tabindex=2 onblur="validatePresent(this, 'inf_whatever');">
        <option value="" SELECTED>Choose</option>
        <option value="OPT1">Option 1</option>
        <option value="OPT2">Option 2</option>
      </select>
      <div id="inf_whatever">&nbsp;</div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Wall of text + wall of code = not helping it. Please be precise.

Comment: oh oh, not sure what that means.  I should cut all the explanation part and just put a couple lines of code that are not working as expected?

Comment: If you could put a fiddle and explain your problem in brief, that would be great.

Comment: I provided a link that shows the issue. my fiddle would not work (first try at that).  It is not that complicated.  the setfocus is not working following a validation function being called onblur.

Comment: `document.getElementById(valfield)` is never going to work if `valfield` isn't a string - have a closer look, `valfield` is already a dom element - its the first var to `commonCheck`, which in turn is the first var of `validatePresent` which finally, gets its value from the inline js, the first var is passed as `this` which ends up being the value you'd get if located the triggering element with JS. Basically, you don't need to find an element with its id, since you've already got the element. ;)

Comment: Further to that, is it your intention to prevent the user from leaving a control once selected until it has a valid value? If your example worked, it would prevent selecting an option until `#misc1` was valid.

Comment: Yes, the point of the field by field validation would be to force an acceptable entry before allowing advancement.

Comment: originally, when I tabbed out of the first field when it was blank, there was a loop created that went from one field to the next and back continuously.  I changed the way it was setting focus to that doc.getelbyid method and that stopped.  I guess because I simply broke it.  I'll put it back the way it was, although it will simply cycle from one field to the other and back when I do...

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function setfocus(valfield)
{

  setTimeout( function () {
      valfield.focus();
  }, 100 );
}
```

passing a closure to `setTimeout` w/o using a global variable.

Comment: Ok, that gives the same result @Axel Amthor, the endless cycling between the two fields upon leaving the first field with nothing entered into the field.

So, the global or the closure have no effect, not doing any focus setting.  if I change the setfocus function to simply be 

    valfield.focus();

it stops the endless cycling of focus, but the focus is then set to the second field following the validation, so it is basically being ignored.